# Lebesgue measure of an intersection of four sets that are contained in [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A_1,A_2,A_3, A_4$ be measurable subsets of $[0,1]$, such that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{4}m(A_k)>3$. Prove that
$$
m\left(\bigcap_{k=1}^{4}A_k\right)>0.
$$

Comment: Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: Assuming that the measure of the intersection is zero, you get a contradiction by inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: @Mark: Care to elaborate?  I don't see how you can do that without some annoyances.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let the superscript $c$ denote the complement in $[0,1]$.  Recall that $m(A)=1-m(A^c)$.  Then $$ m\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^4A_i\right)=1-m\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^4A_i^c\right)\geq 1-\sum_{i=1}^4 m(A_i^c)$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^4 m(A_i)-3>0.$$

The last inequality follows from our starting asumption.

Comment: @ Eric: I do not think that you can use the intersection of [0,1] and A is the same as A complement and the union of A_i complement is not contained in [0,1] so I do not think that you can use the excision property. Would you mine to explain more in detail?

Comment: @Yeonjoo, when he wrote $A_i^c$, he meant complement with respect to $[0,1]$. He is considering $[0,1]$ as the whole space throughout his argument.